# how can i change eclipse from "c/c++" to "java" enviorment?

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse

I did the opposite by mistake and now i can't go back to the java enviorment.
anyoune knows how?
thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There should be a button in the top right corner for changing perspectives.

[image: Java perspective]

You can also get to it through the **Window > Open Perspective** menu.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a concept of "perspective" switch back to the java perspective using the menu